# Can I access to raw RTP stream from a web browser?

Tags: html, web, gstreamer, rtp, npapi

I'm having H264 real-time video stream issuing by gst-rtp-server. Moreover, there is possibility to use an augmented FEC stream from the server to improve performance in noisy environment (like WiFi). FEC works on RTP layer. So, on a client side these two RTP streams must be combined into a final one.

Using GStreamer on a client side inside a dedicated native app works perfectly. But, instead of such native app I'm also considering a modern HTML5 Web browser to receive and render the video stream.

So, formal question: Is it possible to get raw RTP video stream from a modern browser somehow? I need to support iOS, Android, as well as main desktop systems.

Currently, I'm considering GSreamer-based preprocessing on a client side - standalone tiny GStreamer-based service (native GUI-less app) will be activated from a webpage and will perform RTP and FEC-based processing, depaying from RTP and paying to something that HTML5 supports. That new stream then will be issued from the localhost to HTML5's 'video' tag on the webpage.

Alternatively, such GStreamer-based service may be implemented as a NPAPI plugin, but nowdays NPAPI is deprecated way and might be not supported at all.

Any other ideas?

Thanks.